# WPF Loaded event is firing on the wrong tree

Tags: wpf

I have some code which is creating a "fake" control but never adding it to any visual or logical tree (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788731(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
tb.BeginInit();
tb.EndInit();
var size = new Size(1000, 1000); //Any size will do
tb.Measure(size);
tb.Arrange(new Rect(size));
tb.UpdateLayout();
```

For some reason, when UpdateLayout is called on this "disconnected" control, my editor's main control received a "Loaded" event.

The fake control is not connected to the editor window. Why is a disconnected Control triggering Loaded events on other Controls?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Does your "main editor control" _receive_ or _raise_ the `Loaded` event?